# ef-core nested table aggregate functions give "NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor failed"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a nested data model and I'd like to get aggregated data from it grouped by a top level property.
My models for example:

```
public class Scan {
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int ScanUserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ScanItem>? Items { get; set; }
}

public class ScanItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long InventoryScanId { get; set; }
    public double Qty { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to get all Scans grouped by Scan.ScanUserId and then then get the sum of ScanItems.Qty for example per user. My query looks ike this and EF gives the following error:

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'AsQueryable((Unhandled
>   parameter: x).Items)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed

```
from scan in Scans
        .Include(x=>x.ScanUser)
        .Include(x=>x.Items)
    group scan by new { scan.ScanUser.Name, scan.ScanUser.Id } into g
    select new
    {
        UserId = g.Key.Id,
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        LastSyncTime = g.Max(x => x.ScanDate),
        ScanItems = g.Sum(x=>x.Items.Sum(i=>i.Qty))
    }
```

How can I run aggregate functions on the properties of the nested table without evaluating it on the client side?

Comment: I think the `Includes` are unnecessary. Also, why have `Items` be nullable? You can just change to: `public ICollection<ScanItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<ScanItem>();` If Linq-to-SQL tries to call `Sum` on a `null` collection you will get an error.

Comment: @crgolden You're right, Includes are unneccessary and the collection shouldn't be nullable but it didn't help.

Comment: Yes I believe it may be because the inner `Sum` is essentially treated as a type of callback here since it is essentially a `Func` inside a `Func`. I would try to materialize it in the query first (using a `let` variable or something) before building your final `select`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EF Core still can't translate nested aggregates on `GroupBy` result (grouping).

You have to pre calculate the nested aggregates in advance by utilizing the element selector of `GroupBy` (or `element` in query syntax `group element by key`):

```
from scan in Scans
group new { scan.ScanDate, Qty = scan.Items.Sum(i => i.Qty) } // <--
by new { scan.ScanUser.Name, scan.ScanUser.Id } into g
select new
{
    UserId = g.Key.Id,
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    LastSyncTime = g.Max(x => x.ScanDate),
    ScanItems = g.Sum(x => x.Qty) // <--
}
```

**Update: ** for SqlServer the above LINQ query translates to SQL query like this:

```sql
 SELECT [s1].[Id] AS [UserId], [s1].[Name], MAX([s0].[ScanDate]) AS [LastSyncTime], SUM((
      SELECT SUM([s].[Qty])
      FROM [ScanItem] AS [s]
      WHERE [s0].[Id] = [s].[InventoryScanId])) AS [ScanItems]
  FROM [Scan] AS [s0]
  INNER JOIN [ScanUser] AS [s1] ON [s0].[ScanUserId] = [s1].[Id]
  GROUP BY [s1].[Name], [s1].[Id]
```

which as mentioned in the comment generates SQL execution exception *"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."*.

So you really need another approach - use `left join` to flatten the result set before grouping, and then perform the grouping / aggregates on that set:

```
from scan in Scans
from item in scan.Items.DefaultIfEmpty() // <-- left outer join
group new { scan, item } by new { scan.ScanUser.Name, scan.ScanUser.Id } into g
select new
{
    UserId = g.Key.Id,
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    LastSyncTime = g.Max(x => x.scan.ScanDate),
    ScanItems = g.Sum(x => (double?)x.item.Qty) ?? 0
};
```

which now translates to hopefully valid SqlServer SQL query:

```sql
  SELECT [s1].[Id] AS [UserId], [s1].[Name], MAX([s].[ScanDate]) AS [LastSyncTime], COALESCE(SUM([s0].[Qty]), 0.0E0) AS [ScanItems]
  FROM [Scan] AS [s]
  LEFT JOIN [ScanItem] AS [s0] ON [s].[Id] = [s0].[InventoryScanId]
  INNER JOIN [ScanUser] AS [s1] ON [s].[ScanUserId] = [s1].[Id]
  GROUP BY [s1].[Name], [s1].[Id]
```

Comment: Thanks it looked very promising but it's giving an SqlException now: `SqlException: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Comment: @Perrier Bummer. Solving EF Core query limitation just to hit SQL query limitation :-( Anyway, see the update, hopefully it should work.